# Accessing Linux container from Windows host

Tags: docker-network, linux-containers

I have Linux (CentOS-7) containers which are running on top of Windows docker host. I can ping from Linux container (172.17.x.x) to Windows host (10.10.x.x) but I cannot do the opposite. My Windows version is 10 (firewall off).

Comment: You mean pinging from Windows to container directly?

Comment: Please provide more information on what kind of Docker setup you are using? Virtualbox (via docker toolbox) or HyperV?